# How can I debug new detectors in find-sec-bugs without repackaging the entire project?

Tags: java, find-sec-bugs

How to quickly debug and modify code?

I am not a professional java developer and I am confused about how to debug this find-sec-bugs project. Whenever I add a new detector, do I need to package the entire project and replace plugins.jar in findsecbugs-cli, can I debug the source code I wrote directly with IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it directly in your IDE. Take a look at the [test](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/blob/master/findsecbugs-plugin/src/test/java/com/h3xstream/findsecbugs/file/FileUploadFilenameDetectorTest.java#L29-L54) [cases](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/blob/master/findsecbugs-plugin/src/test/java/com/h3xstream/findsecbugs/PredictableRandomDetectorTest.java#L31-L118). Every test case run SpotBugs with the FSB plugin loaded and do assertions on the results. It is also an opportunity to profile/debug/trace the execution from the IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse).

If you want to attach to the CLI, you will need to use remote debugging. You can do this by adding
`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:8000`
to the java command located in [findsecbugs.sh](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/blob/master/cli/findsecbugs.sh#L20) or [findsecbugs.bat](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/blob/master/cli/findsecbugs.bat#L2).

Ref: [Java Application Remote Debugging](https://www.baeldung.com/java-application-remote-debugging)